# How to boot Ubuntu Live(Ubiquity) Installer from PXE server?

Tags: nfs, pxe

I'm trying to boot ubuntu ubiquity live installer over network. I have read many tutorial. Including [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveCDNetboot).

Here is what I have done.
Installed [netboot.tar.gz](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz) on my dnsmasq server. Default setup working fine.

```
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/tmp/mnt/JM500/netboot
```

But I need to boot live installer environment. Then I created NFS export (/tmp/mnt/JM500 -> /mnt/JM500) and I tried many configuration. But non of them working.

Error message is something like this

```
vmlinuz loading ok
initrd loading ok. Booting Linux kernel failed: invalid argument.
```

Here is some configuration I tried.

```
label live
    menu label ^Ubuntu Unity 20.04 live
    kernel OS/UU/casper/vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=OS/UU/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.50.1:/mnt/JM500 file=/netboot/OS/UU/preseed/ubuntu.seed
    
label 2004u
    menu label ^Ubuntu Unity 20.04tftp
    menu default
    kernel OS/UU/casper/vmlinuz
    initrd OS/UU/casper/initrd
    append auto=true url=tftp://192.168.50.1/OS/UU/pressed/ubuntu.seed vga=normal ---

label ISO
    menu label ubuntu-unity-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
    linux memdisk
    append iso initrd=OS/ubuntu-unity-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso raw
```

Can you tell me what wrong is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the netboot archive files to boot the live-installer.  The netboot archive is part of the *legacy installer* (debian-installer).  The *live installer* (subiquity) is different and requires using boot files from its image.  The article you link mentions this.  Emphasis mine

> Put /casper/vmlinuz and /casper/initrd.gz (**from the live CD**) where your TFTP server can serve them up

I usually refer to the instructions at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510

The steps include how to mount the *live server* iso and copy the needed files.

```
# wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
# mount ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt
# cp /mnt/casper/{vmlinuz,initrd} /srv/tftp/
```